# Specialized SAT solver (?)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, sat, sat-solvers

([Context](https://fuzzypixelz.com/blog/absolut/))

Given two byte arrays of length 16, say `L` and `H`, one can define a mapping `M` from the set of all bytes to itself in the following way.

If `0 <= b < 256` is a byte, let `lo(b)` denote the lower 4 bits of `b` and let `hi(b)` denote the higher 4 bits of `b`.

Let `L[i]` (resp. `H[i]`) denote the `i`-th byte of `L` (resp. `H`). Also let `L[i, j]` (resp. `H[i, j]`) denote the `j`-th bit of the `i`-th byte of `L` (resp. `H`).

With all this, we can define `M(b) = L[lo(b)] & H[hi(b)]`.

Where `&` is bitwise AND.

If we want `M` to satisfy a constraint of the form `M(b) == m`. Then `L` and `H` have to be chosen accordingly (if possible). This constraint is equivalent to `L[lo(b)] & H[hi(b)] == m`. Or more precisely to `L[lo(b), j] & H[hi(b), j] == m[j]`, where `m[j]` is the `j`-th bit of `m`.

In general, any equation of the form `X & Y = Z` where `X, Y, Z` are bits (or booleans) is equivalent the following boolean clauses in propositional logic:

```
~X | ~Y | Z
X | ~Z
Y | ~Z
```

Where `~X` is the negation of `X` and `|` is bitwise OR.

The last remaining piece of the problem is the fact that the `m` bytes should be distinct from each other (assuming more than one constraint). Two bytes are non-equal if at least one of their bits aren't. Two bits `X` and `Y` are non-equal iff the following clauses hold:

```
X | Y
~X | ~Y
```

Hence this problem can be solved using 3-SAT. I have three question with regards to this:

1. Is my problem equivalent to 3-SAT, i.e. can an arbitrary 3-SAT problem be reduced to it? Or is it further simplifiable into something less difficult?
2. If not, do you see an algorithm for solving it efficiently?
3. If yes, would a "simple" CDCL-based solver suffice? (We're dealing with around 3000 clauses and 300 variables).

I have already tried a basic backtracking solver and it failed to terminate even after multiple hours. I'm writing this after having spent multiple weeks thinking about this, and having failed to come up with a specialised algorithm. I could of course just use an off-the-shelf SAT solver but I'm interested in solving this as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me do the original problem by hand to illustrate the essence of this problem.

I’m going to write bytes 0x2C as pairs of nibbles (2, C). If we consider 1-bit outputs, then the functions that we can express are, for every set of nibbles S and set of nibbles T, the indicator function of S × T. The original paper assigns each class a separate bit:

- {2} × {C} = {(2, C)}
- {3} × {A} = {(3, A)}
- {5, 7} × {B, D} = {(5, B), (5, D), (7, B), (7, D)}
- {0} × {9, A, D} = {(0, 9), (0, A), (0, D)}
- {2} × {0} = {(2, 0)}.

I’ve elided the table values because they don’t matter. That points to the main weakness of the SAT formulation: it’s highly symmetric, and basic branching strategies will struggle. Sophisticated SAT solvers can detect symmetry and prune redundant branches, but the logic is *complicated,* and you really don’t want to implement it yourself for one application.

I’m going to assume that all of the bytes that don’t fall in any class should map to 0. Then a necessary condition is that every class can be expressed as a product. If there are at most as many classes as output bits, then this condition is also sufficient, and you don’t need a SAT solver. Otherwise, you have a restricted *test cover problem.* I don’t have an NP-hardness proof, but I would be surprised if it weren’t NP-hard.

Comment: How exactly does encoding classes as nibble set products lead back to table values? Why does mapping non-classified byte to 0 make every class expressible as a product? (Could any non-zero value also work?)

Comment: @fuzzypixelz For each class, choose a distinct output bit b, and assuming that the class is represented as the product H x L, set b in the high lookup table whenever the index belongs to H, and set b in the low index table whenever the index belongs to L. If you're willing to consider a nonzero value for the catch-all, then the condition for the existence of the solution gets more complicated, but it's still going to be some sort of (likely NP-hard, IMO) test cover problem.

Comment: I appreciate that you delimited a fairly approachable but still useful subset of the problem. Your approach even works if we swap bitwise AND for bitwise OR by setting all bits of the catch-all class to 1. I have a few more questions however. What do you mean by 'symmetric' and why is a sophisticated solver needed given the relative 'small' size of the problem?

Comment: @fuzzypixelz For any permutation π of the output byte, we can apply π to each element of each table and still have a valid solution. So we end up having up to 8! = 40320 times as many solutions as we should without symmetry breaking.